# Store XML data as relational data into Oracle tables using Java and XMLType

Tags: java, xml, oracle11g, xmltype

I want to store xml data into an Oracle 11g table as relational storage, not as CLOB or Binary storage. Then I should also be able to query and fetch this data from table into an XML file.

Any hint on how to write java code using XMLType to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Start with the online [Oracle XML DB Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/toc.htm), specifically:

  - The [Java DOM API for XMLType](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb11jav.htm#g1039140)
  - [Writing Oracle XML DB Applications in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb23jv1.htm#g1050187)
  - [Loading XML Content into Oracle XML DB Using Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb03usg.htm#CEGFECFH)
- See also the online Java reference doc: [Oracle Database XML Java API Reference, 11g Release 2 (11.2), Class XMLType](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10769/oracle/xdb/XMLType.html)